# Linear Discriminant Analysis transform function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lda, dimensionality-reduction

```
x = data.values
y = target.values
lda = LDA(solver='eigen', shrinkage='auto',n_components=2)
df_lda = lda.fit(x,y).transform(x)
df_lda.shape
```

This is the small part of the code. I am trying to reduce the dimensionality to the most discriminative directions. To my understanding the `transform()` function projects data to maximize class separation for my data set and should return an array of shape `(n_samples, n_components)`

But my `df_lda` is of shape (614, 1).

What am I missing here ? Or is my data not linearly separable?.

Comment: Whats ```x.shape``` (and maybe type)?

Comment: `x.shape = (614, 6)` and `x.dtype = ('float64')`

Comment: How many classes (distinct values) do you have in `target.values`?

Comment: aahh thanks I think it struck me when u asked. For 2 classes this reduces to exactly 1 discriminant vector. Am I right?

Comment: That is correct. For two classes, there is only one component in the LDA transform.

Comment: I was planning to use `SVM`'s. I tried PCA. I just wanted to compare the results. Is there any alternative way to `LDA`

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. According to LDA, you already have the most discriminative direction. There are some other options out there (depending on what you're trying to achieve). One technique that comes to mind is [Decision Boundary Feature Extraction](http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1215&context=ecetr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case of `K` distinct classes in `target.values` there are `K-1` components in the transformed data (without further dimensionality reduction). Since you only have two classes in your data set, there is only one transformed component so you cannot get more components than that.

I suppose it might by helpful for sklearn to issue a warning when you request more than are available.